# Reading multiple csv files

Tags: r

I need to read multiple csv files and print the first six values for each of these. I tried this code but it is obviously wrong because the value of di is overwritten each iteration of the loop. How can I read multiple files?

```
library(xlsx)
for(i in 1:7){
    di = read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
    print(di)
}
d = list(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7)
lapply(d,head)
```

Comment: You can use the list.files function: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import multiple .csv files at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep you data frames in a list, rather than assigning each to a new object.

#### Option 1:

```
fs <- dir(pattern = ".csv")
d <- list()
for (i in seq_along(fs)) {
    d[[i]] <- read.csv(fs[[1]])
    print(head(d[[i]]))
    }
```

#### Option 2:

```
fs <- dir(pattern = ".csv")
d <- lapply(fs, read.csv)
lapply(d, head)
```

Using option 1, you need to initialize an empty list to populate and assign with double bracket `[[` notation. Using option 2, you don't need to initialize an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by if you want to just print the 6 lines or store them and if you want to keep the remainder of the csv files or not. Let's say all you want is to print the 6 lines, then, assuming you know the file names you can do this with

```
print(read.csv(filename, nlines = 6))
```

And repeat for each file. Alternatively if you want to save each file then you could do

```
f1 <- read.csv(filename, nlines = 6)
```

Repeat for each and use `print(head)`.

Alternatively using your method but fixing the overwrite problem:

```
library(xlsx)
for(i in 1:7)
  assign(paste0("d",i), read.csv(file.choose(),header=T))

  lapply(list(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7),head)
```

The use of `assign` dynamically assigns names so that each is unique and doesn't overwrite each other, which I think is what you were aiming for. This isn't very 'elegant' though but fits with your chosen method

Comment: I want to read 7 csv files and also save each of them. I wanted to know if there is way of doing it without writing read.csv statement 7 times. Because if there are several files it will be tedious to write a read statement for each one of them.

Comment: If they are all in one directory then you could do:

`x <- as.list(list.files(pattern = "csv"))`
`for(i in 1:length(x))`
  `assign(paste0("d",i), read.csv(x[[i]], header=T))`